# where in Ubuntu 14.04 to set env vars to be default for all processes and daemons

Tags: ubuntu, init

I want to set the LANG variable to a default for all daemons started by upstart (init) in Ubuntu-server 14.04.

I've already set it in /etc/default/locale and /etc/environment.  Those both affect interactive sessions, but not the daemons and other processes spawned by init/upstart.

Comment: Daemons may disregard any locale set in the environment, and for good reasons.

Comment: True, however, some daemons may be written expecting to be in a specific encoding types.  Not all devs design their daemons as robustly as others.

Comment: That's why any self respecting daemon will unset any LANG, LANGUAGE or LC_* environment variables and call `setlocale (LC_ALL, "C")`.